# onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

Cant figure out why onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState isnt outputting my Logcat messages when I click the home button and when I restore the app respectively.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        count++;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
        Log.d("TAG", count + " was restored");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        count = savedInstanceState.getInt("count");
        Log.d("TAG", count + " was restored");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` are called at specific times in the activity's lifecycle.

[image: Activity lifecycle]

As you can see, for `onSaveInstanceState()` to be called, the activity needs to be destroyed by the operating system. Pressing the Home button will only call the `onPause()` method.

To debug the `onSaveInstanceState()` method, go into `Settings -> Developer options` on the Android device, and in the `Apps` section, check the box beside `Kill app back button`. Now, a long press on the back button should kill the visible app and notify you with a toast. Opening the app again will call `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

If this option is not present on your device, or if you're using an emulator,  follow the instructions here on how to immediately destroy activities to test `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`:
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-devtools.html

Answer (score 1):

Clicking the home button isn't enough to kill the app.  That just pauses it.  onSave/onRestore are only called when the framework is going to kill the activity and restore it later on.  Just minimizing it doesn't do that.